# VBA find duplicates in column and list row number?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following VBA code to search a column for duplicate values.
If found then i want to populate cell Q1 with a hyperlink to that row number.

Here's what i have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 15 And Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then             
        If Evaluate("Countif(O:O," & Target.Address & ")") > 1 Then
            Range("P1").Value = "DUPLICATE ENTRY EXISTS"            
            Range("Q1").Formula= "=HYPERLINK()"                     
        End If             
    End If

End Sub
```

Please can someone show me how to get the row number of the duplicate value?

Comment: Can there be multiple duplicates for an entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the `Range.Find` method to accomplish both checking for duplicates and getting the Address.  You may want to consider clearing the hyperlink and the cell at some point in time.  You could check to see if there are any duplicates, and clear if that is the case; or you could check for multiple duplicates, and output them in sequential cells.  All kinds of things.

**EDIT** You also need to decide how to handle the situation in which `Target` is a multicell range.  Consider the situation where `Target` is entirely within Column `O`, and where it is not.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim S As String

Set R = Columns(15)

If Not Intersect(Target, R) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set C = R.Find(what:=Target.Text, after:=Target, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    If C.Address <> Target.Address Then
        S = C.Address(external:=True)
        S = Mid(S, InStr(S, "]") + 1)
        Range("q1").Hyperlinks.Delete
        Range("Q1").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("q1"), _
            Address:="", SubAddress:=S, _
            TextToDisplay:=C.Address, ScreenTip:="Duplicate Entry"

    Else 'Clear Q1 if no duplicate
        Range("Q1").Clear
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: nice Ron, I knew I used to have a cleaner approach then the "Algorithm" I used below

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks.  I note I just wrote the address and not the hyperlink.  I will change that

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks.  When writing macros, in general, I prefer to use VBA rather than writing formulas back to the worksheet (unless there is a specific reason to perform the operation on the worksheet, rather than in VBA).  Here we are making changes based on a worksheet event, so there doesn't seem to be a good reason to do this as a formula.

Comment: you should also check for `C` not being `Nothing`

Comment: @user3598756   I did not think this necessary.  When you tested this, how did you set up your worksheet so that it would be an issue?

Comment: Not testing anything. Just seeing a Find() and thus automatically calling that check. I didn't analyze if OP's specific data structure doesn't need that

Comment: @user3598756 The data structure is irrelevant. You should analyze the algorithm.  `Target` is in column O and the `Range` being searched is Column O.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, may be my _data structure_ definition was not that clear. I was actually meaning "where _things_ are taken from and searched in for". So if `Target` always belongs to the same range wherein it is being searched for, then it's positive that it doesn't call for the `Nothing` check. While there could be some room for checking `Target` is not a multi-cell range (though unlikely, it's a possibility), which would make the `...Find(...) ...` statement throw an error out of  `Target.Text`.

Comment: @user3598756 And when you examine the code I provided, you would see there is no way that Target (unless it comprises multiple cells), can be other than in the same range.  Do you see that now?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, which is precisely what I wrote in my last comment. don't you agree?

Comment: @user3598756 I wondered why, since the code restricted `What` to the same column being searched, you bothered writing *you should also check for C not being Nothing*

Comment: that was before I wrote _"Not testing anything. Just seeing a Find() and thus automatically calling that check. I didn't analyze if OP's specific data structure doesn't need that"_, and then  _" may be my data structure definition was not that clear. I was actually meaning "where things are taken from and searched in for". So if Target always belongs to the same range wherein it is being searched for, then it's positive that it doesn't call for the Nothing check"_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135717/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-user3598756).

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it's not as simple as I would like it to be, but it works.

Once you find that the current value entered in column "O" has a duplicate, I am using the `Find` method to find the next match.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 15 And Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then

        If Evaluate("Countif(O:O," & Target.Address & ")") > 1 Then
            Range("P1").Value = "DUPLICATE ENTRY EXISTS"

            Dim RowDup As Long
            Dim FindRng As Range
            Dim LastRow As Long

            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Target.Column).End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in Column "O"

            If Target.Row = 1 Then
                Set FindRng = Range(Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column), Cells(LastRow, Target.Column))
            Else ' define a search range, substract target cell from active range in column "O"
                Set FindRng = Application.Union(Range(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(Target.Row - 1, Target.Column)), Range(Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column), Cells(LastRow, Target.Column)))
            End If

            ' find thr row number in the column O (except Target cell)
            RowDup = FindRng.Find(What:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

            ' get the hyperlink to the cell where the first dupliacte exists
            Range("Q1").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & Range(Cells(RowDup, Target.Column), Cells(RowDup, Target.Column)).Address & ")"
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```